# How to using label and numbering in Latex

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

When using label twice, the numbering appears the first time like this
[image]

and the second time is like this

[image]
.

How can I make them from the same writing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Whatever is happening is due to code you are withholding. While I strongly suspect some users here can read minds, unfortunately most of us can't.

Comment: The latex command `\label` has no effect on the printed output at all.